# changing datastore entires via remote api is not reflected on running instances

Tags: google-app-engine

I am updating entires in the datastore via the remote API in Java.

If I query for the updated entry in the app engine dashboard I am able to see the new version.
But my servlet that runs on an instance that was running before the update and already served read the datastore entry still sees the old version.

If I manually shut down the instance and a new one boots up, it serves up the new version just fine.
If I delete the entry from the datastore through the app engine dashboard the old running instance can not read the entry anymore as expected.

This seems like a caching issue on running instances somehow. It seems like the remote API fails to tell running instances that certain datastore entries can not be cached anymore.

Is there something I can do to change this on the remote API?
Or should I be filing a bug?

*Note:* I am not caching anything in memcache or the RAM of the instance.

**Update**
This is how I update a new Entity through the remote API:

```
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Entity entity = new Entity("DocModel", "somekey");
entity.setProperty("html", "someProperty");
ds.put(entity);
```

This is how a read the values with a servlet using JDO:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
DocModel docModel = pm.getObjectById(DocModel.class, "someKey");
```

Here is the JDO class:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class DocModel {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent
  private String name;

  @Persistent
  private Text html;

  public DocModel(String path, String html) {
    this.name = path;
    this.html = new Text(html);
  }

  public String getHtml() {
    return html.getValue();
  }

  public String getPath() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

**Update2**

This seems to be JDO related. I changed reads to use the datastore API and now I am seeing updated values. With JDO those updated values will **NEVER** be seen (I tested about 10 minutes a couple of times). I need to kill the instance for the values to propagate.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a consistency issue (if you are 100% sure that no caching of entries / the PMF is going on).

- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries
- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries

Are you sure JDO is using strong consistency? You can force set that via

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(DocModel.class);
q.addExtension("datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency", "STRONG");
```

Imho JDO uses strong consistency by default (as specified in the jdoconfig.xml), but I'd double check the jdoconfig.xml).

**Update**: Strong consistency is NOT the default for JDO (despite what the docs say) => therefore it makes sense what you are seeing, and setting consistency to STRONG might fix your issue (https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6326).

Comment: STRONG consistency won't work unless you have ancestor queries.

Comment: this is a JDO isue. Removing JDO and using the datastore API directly seems to fix it. JDO seems to be caching values for a long time somewhere. I am fine with eventual consistency, but with JDO the change never seems to come through (tried for 10 minutes a couple of times)

Comment: I don't dare to ask - but are you closing the pm after usage? (pm.close();) I mean - usually the PMF/pm is static and maybe this leads to the root cause... just guessing...

Answer (score 1):

That's [eventual consistency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency) and you need to run ancestor queries if you want to be sure you see all the latest writes in your queries

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like a bug, you'll need to explicitly clear memcache yourself.  And if your instances are caching in local memory, you'll also have to clear that yourself.  None of those are part of the datastore api.

Comment: I am not using memcache or caching in the RAM of the instance

Comment: What lib/framework are you using in Java? Are you sure it doesn't use memcache under the hood ?  You instance has to be caching something based on you description of the behaviour you are experiencing. How quickly are you doing the query after an update, you may also be seeing HRD eventual consistancy at work.  You should probably provide more details - type of query, timeframe between put and query.  I use remote api all of the time, and never experience problems like those you describe except when instance/memcache caches are in effect.

Comment: Showing some code on how you do your fetches would make a huge difference.  If you're not doing any caching, it could be eventual consistency behavior.  But that would depend on how you're fetching the data - some fetch operations like get-by-key/id or transactions would be fully consistent.

Unless you or your framework is caching, GAE itself doesn't do any automatic caching on your instances.

Comment: the datastore will not cache in Memcache if you don't explicitly instruct this yourself or your framework does (cfr. objectify). It is simply not true that you should explicitly clear memcache yourself.